# How to pass parameter of oracle sql script file to sqlplus from shell prompt?

Tags: sql, linux, bash, oracle

**Objective:** To invoke sqlplus with sql script file path as parameter from shell prompt

**Scenario:**

logged in as root and would like to execute the sql script file as oracle

**Command:**

```
sudo -u oracle bash -c ". ~/.bash_profile; sqlplus / as sysdba@/tmp/downloads/oracle/instl/script/createschema.sql
```

**Expected:** sql commands in createschema.sql are to be executed

**Actual:** getting only sql prompt

Also, tried:

a)

```
sudo -u oracle bash -c ". ~/.bash_profile; sqlplus@/tmp/downloads/oracle/instl/script/createschema.sql / as sysdba
```

b)

```
sudo -u oracle bash -c ". ~/.bash_profile; sqlplus -s /as sysdba << EOF
```

whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode; set echo off; set heading off; /tmp/downloads/oracle/instl/script/createschema.sql; exit; EOF"

but getting error in both a) and b).

Please guide me in invoking sqlplus with sql script file path as parameter from shell prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 1

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"Scott\"
password=\"@T!ger\"
host=10.x.xx.xxx
port=1521
service=esmd
ezconnect=$host:$port/$service

echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password
echo host:      $host
echo port:      $port
echo service:   $servive
echo ezconnect  $ezconnect

echo -e 'show user \n  select 1 from dual; \n select sysdate from dual; \nexit;' |  sqlplus -s  $username/$password@$ezconnect
```

Output:

```
oracle@esmd:~> ./test_echo.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
host: 10.x.xx.xxx
port: 1521
service:
ezconnect 10.x.xx.xxx:1521/esmd
USER is "Scott"

         1
----------
         1


SYSDATE
---------
19-FEB-20

oracle@esmd:~>
```

Example 2

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"Scott\"
password=\"@T!ger\"


echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password

testoutput=$(sqlplus -s $username/$password  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual;
@ulcase1.sql
exit;
EOF
)

echo $testoutput
```

Output:

```
oracle@esmd:~> ./test_Upper_case.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
USER is "Scott" 19-02-2020 15:08 Test passed
oracle@esmd:~>
```

Example 3  test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo  -H -E  -u oracle  -s "/opt/oracle/test_Upper_case.sh"
```

Output

```
esmd:~ # ./test.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
USER is "Scott" 19-02-2020 15:50 Test passed
```

/opt/oracle/test_Upper_case.sh

```
!/bin/sh

username=\"Scott\"
password=\"@T!ger\"


echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password

testoutput=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $username/$password  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual;
@/opt/oracle/ulcase1.sql
exit;
EOF
)

echo $testoutput
```